# select the data from latest partition (partitioned by date) without scanning the full athena table

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

is there anyway I can select the data from latest partition (partitioned by date) without scanning the full athena table?
I wanted to select data from a table based on the latest partition (and the partition by date)
I can  take the latest partition by select max(date_p) from "database"."table.partitions" which requires some MB's to scan. But I when I use it filter the table by using CTE, it scans the full table.
Any solutions ?
edit: query updated

```
with t1 as
(select max(date_p) as date_p from "database"."table$partitions" )

select * from t1
left join "database"."table" t2 ON t1.date_p = t2.date_p
```

Comment: Can you please post the SQL which leads to the full scan? Your current query does not looks like a correct one.

Comment: Why not use the actual last-day date in the filter? If you know that the partitions are by day (or week/month/year...), you can use that fact to calculate the WHERE clause of your query.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks syntactically wrong. Also, you're not using `max(date_p)` in the join in any way.

I'd recommend to simply use the pattern below. But I suppose the join should also work if done correctly.

```sql
select * from t1 where date_p = (
  select max(date_p) from "database"."table$partitions"
)
```

But note, the result isn't necessarily the same as

```sql
select * from t1 where date_p = (
  select max(date_p) from t1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Using Max(date) takes a lot of time to return the dataset. But if we pass hardcoded max(date) value, the dataset returns faster.